# Excel Status Bar Re-appearing

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following when the workbook opens to hide the Status Bar

```
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
```

I have found that if I minimise / restore the workbook the Status Bar re-appears. Is there a way to prevent this.

Comment: Perhaps you have an workbook event that reinstates it? If *I* run that command directly in the 'Immediate' window, the Status Bar is hidden and nothing but setting it back to True will make it reappear.

Comment: Application.DisplayStatusBar = True does not appear in the workbook. Is there another Application or ActiveWindow event that can cause it to be reinstated even though it is not explicitly requested

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I can't recreate your issue at all. I've hidden the bar and no amount of minimise/restore causes it to reappear. (Full Excel  closure excepted). I'm using 64bit Excel 2013.